# Limiting the Y-axis width for a horizontal FusionChart

Tags: css, width, fusioncharts, ellipsis, yaxis

**Using FusionCharts**

I am attempting to limit the y-axis width of a horizontal fusion chart.

**Current Behavior**
The y-axis label becomes too long for the width of the chart so that you see more label than you actually see bars on the chart.

**Desired Behavior**
I would like to define a max-length or max-width for the y-axis label and show an ellipsis if the label is too long for that width.

**Example Label**
Existing: I am a very long label and shrink the chart area
Desired: I am a very long label a...

[In this example I would only want to show the part of the label that is in the red box:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGaft.png)

Answer (score 0):

Any way I found a way to implement this, with the help of 'maxLabelWidthPercent' and 'minLabelWidthPercent'

maxLabelWidthPercent - Restricts the maximum length of data labels in terms of percentage of the charts width that the data labels can occupy. If a data label is longer than the specified percentage width then it will either be wrapped or get truncated.

minLabelWidthPercent - Restricts the minimum length of data labels in terms of percentage of the chart's width that the data labels can occupy.

[Refer the link for attributes details] : https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes/bar2d

```
"minLabelWidthPercent":"10",
"maxLabelWidthPercent":"20"
```

[Here is Demo ] : http://jsfiddle.net/p7vyjbax/